# My Google map not displayed in android eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

Please help me i am unable to display the google map in android eclipse.Even i have created my SHA1 and go to google console and make  android key for map.

This is my Main Activity code.

```
public class Main-Activity extends Activity {
    // Google Map
    private Google-Map google-Map;
    @Override
    protected void on-create(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.on-Create(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            google-Map.setMapType(Google-Map.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            on
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            double latitude = 17.385044;
            double longitude = 78.486671;
            // lets place some 10 random markers
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // random latitude and logitude
                double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                        longitude);
                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .title("Hello Maps " + i);
                Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                        + randomLocation[1]);
                // changing marker color
                if (i == 0)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                if (i == 1)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                if (i == 2)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
                if (i == 3)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                if (i == 4)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                if (i == 5)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                if (i == 6)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                if (i == 7)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                if (i == 8)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
                if (i == 9)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
                if (i == 9) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {
        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

This my Xml part::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This My Mainfest part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.example.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
   <permission
        android:name="info.example.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="info.example.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">


        <activity
            android:name="info.example.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!-- Google API Key -->
          <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBZMlkOv4sj-M5JO9p6wksdax4TEjDVLgo"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

please suggest me to for find out this problem.i am very keen to do this work so please help me. this is very important part in my android project so i am getting this section in my android application. Thanks in advance for help me to fine this problem.**

Comment: What is your logcat error?

Comment: no error coming in logcat

Comment: Any warning or something, while loading the application.

Comment: `Google-Map`, is this just a typo in your Question or you have used it in your code?

Comment: no any warning while loading application

Comment: @Nano Web In Which way run your app? Emulater or real device?

Comment: is this your key `AIzaSyDMA0yZeiorQW9zwOIF8QNNJvPqRVm5KC4` or this one `AIzaSyBZMlkOv4sj-M5JO9p6wksdax4TEjDVLgo` ??

Comment: i have posted my menifest

Comment: i an running my code in real device

Comment: @NanoWeb you have mentioned the wrong key in the manifest .

Comment: @Nano Web Are you getting blank screen instand of map?

Comment: Then please suggest me what kind of key mentioned in manifest

Comment: Yes i am getting blank screen in my device

Comment: So problem is wrong api key assigned

Comment: i was assigned android key in my manifest file and  add google play service lib in my project

Comment: You need to follow some tutorial and make sure you don't miss any step. 
[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm) might help.